# Haskell remove trailing and leading whitespace from a file

Tags: string, haskell, io

Let's say I have a file

```
mary had a little lamb
         It's fleece was white as snow    
Everywhere   
    the child went   
   The lamb, the lamb was sure to go, yeah
```

How would I read the file as a string, and remove the trailing and leading whitespace? It could be spaces or tabs. It would print like this after removing whitespace:

```
mary had a little lamb
It's fleece was white as snow
Everywhere
the child went
The lamb, the lamb was sure to go, yeah
```

Here's what I have currently:

```
import Data.Text as T

readTheFile = do
    handle <- openFile "mary.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    putStrLn contents
    hClose handle
    return(contents)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    file <- readTheFile
    file2 <- (T.strip file)
    return()
```

Comment: Could you post the code? I'm new to haskell and don't know much

Comment: Consider elaborating on your code sample.  Explain why it is not doing what you want. To help you, that's the first thing we're going to have to figure out, and you can save us from having to deduce that from your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code suggests a few misunderstandings about Haskell so let's go through your code before getting to the solution.

```
import Data.Text as T
```

You're using `Text`, great!  I suggest you also use the IO operations that read and write `Text` types instead of what is provided by the prelude which works on `String`s (linked lists of characters).  That is, `import Data.Text.IO as T`

```
readTheFile = do
    handle <- openFile "mary.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    putStrLn contents
    hClose handle
    return(contents)
```

Oh, hey, the use of `hGetContents` and manually opening and closing a file can be  error prone.  Consider `readTheFile = T.readFile "mary.txt"`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    file <- readTheFile
    file2 <- (T.strip file)
    return()
```

Two issues here.

*Issue one* Notice here you have used `strip` as though it's an IO action... but it isn't.  I suggest you learn more about IO and binding (do notation) vs let-bound variables.  `strip` computes a new value of type `Text` and presumably you want to do something useful with that value, like write it.

*Issue two* Stripping the whole file is different than stripping each line one at a time.  I suggest you read mathk's answer.

So in the end I think you want:

```
-- Qualified imports are accessed via `T.someSymbol`
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text as T

-- Not really need as a separate function unless you want to also
-- put the stripping here too.
readTheFile :: IO T.Text
readTheFile = T.readFile "mary.txt"

-- First read, then strip each line, then write a new file.
main :: IO ()
main =
    do file <- readTheFile
       let strippedFile = T.unlines $ map T.strip $ T.lines file
       T.writeFile "newfile.txt" (T.strip strippedFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution for what you are looking for:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

main = do
  trimedFile <- (T.unlines . map T.strip . T.lines) <$> T.readFile "mary.txt"
  T.putStr trimedFile
```

`strip` from `Data.Text` is doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file or process the file one line at a time then

```
> intercalate " ".words $ "   The lamb, the lamb    was sure to go, yeah   "
"The lamb, the lamb was sure to go, yeah"
```

But, `unwords` with no parameter is better than `intercalate " "` and it neither has to be imported.